# How to hide payment gateways for free products in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, payment-method

I have a free product on woocommerce. But the stripe payment gateway ask for credit card payment even if it is free with a total of 0€. User can’t checkout without filling the stripe cc form.

Credit card info are not necessary when the product is for free.

I am sure I am not the only one on earth who add some free product in a woocommerce shop. How can I hide this "credticard form" in the check out page in order to let my members access to my free product? Do you know any plugin or hack?

Thanks

Comment: this example can easily be adapted to meet your question https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-payment-method-for-specific-category/ if you still can't figure it out, adjust your question and add the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated:** You can use the following to disable checkout payment when there is only free products in cart:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', 'filter_cart_needs_payment_callback', 100, 2 );
function filter_cart_needs_payment_callback( $needs_payment, $cart ) {
    return $cart->subtotal > 0 ? $needs_payment : false;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test it asap.

Comment: Ok. I tested. It hide the stripe form but it show an error message "Invalid payment method" when I clicked on "Place order" button => http://prntscr.com/rvofho

Comment: Perfect! Thats what I was looking for.